# How to run code after writing HTTP response

Tags: rest, go, asynchronous

I have a REST API, and my objective is to push all the response information to my GCP Pubsub after writing it to the client. To achieve this, I've implemented a middleware in my code. Here's an example of how it looks:

```
func CreateRoutes(api *mux.Router) {
    // all my routers
    api.HandleFunc("/products", HandlerProducts).Methods("POST")
    api.HandleFunc("/items", HandlerItems).Methods("POST")
    ...
    
    // my middleware
    api.Use(MyPush)
}

func MyPush(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Copy the response to "buf" to do more logic
        buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

        wrapped := httptest.NewRecorder()
        handler.ServeHTTP(wrapped, r)

        for k, v := range wrapped.Header() {
            w.Header()[k] = v
        }
        w.WriteHeader(wrapped.Code)
        io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(w, buf), wrapped.Body)
        
        // More logic with Pubsub here
        ...
    }
}

func main() {
    ...

    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    api := r.PathPrefix("/v0").Subrouter()
    CreateRoutes(api)

    srv := &http.Server{
        ...
        Handler: r, // Pass our instance of gorilla/mux in.
    }

    // Run our server in a goroutine so that it doesn't block.
    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    ...
}
```

In fact, the `MyPush()` function does the job, but it seems to impact the performance of my REST API. I've noticed that the responses from my API take longer to reach the client when this middleware is active, i.e when I remove the middleware, the response time returns to normal and there is no delay. I have a feeling that the `MyPush()` function is executed before the response is written (since it is a middleware, correct ?), so it does take more time !?!

Is there a way to push my data without causing this problem? How can I ensure that the `MyPush()` function is executed after the response has been written? Or is there a way to run it asynchronously to prevent any impact on the latency of my API? What should I do to achieve my goal please?

If I misunderstand something, please feel free to point it out. I truly appreciate that.

Comment: Try setting the content-length header on the response. that might prevent the client from waiting until connection is closed.

Comment: Instead of performing complex logic as part of your request, run a separate goroutine to handle it and write the necessary data to it over a channel. This introduces almost no additional processing time to your request.

Comment: As @larsks suggested, you can run your Pubsub code in a separate goroutine. Do not use Context from HTTP Request, though. It will be cancelled when request is finished.

Comment: @larsks thank you for your suggestion. Could you please provide me with any relevant documentation or resources that I could reference to please?

Comment: Some options: (1) Start a goroutine from the handler to do the work: `go doSomething(anArgument)`.   A possible danger with this approach is that the number of goroutiens grows without bound. (2) As suggested by Burak, modify MyPush to set the content length response header and call `doSomething` at the end handler function. The identity transfer encoding is when the content length is specified.